# How can I create a Hierarchical block with GNURadio Companion?

Tags: hierarchical, gnuradio, gnuradio-companion

I am trying to create a Hierarchical block using the GNURadio Companion GUI.  Answers I've found in other posts say to select the blocks you want to incorporate, then go to More -> Create Hier.   Then a new screen is supposed to appear.  However, doing "Create Hier" with any combinations of blocks selected seems to do nothing.

Am I doing something wrong, or is there a problem with my GRC?

Answer (score 15):

It's very simple. You just start with a new flow graph in GRC, and use **Pad Source**s as input, and **Pad Sink**s as output.

If you want to let the user configure something, use a **Parameter** GRC block.

You must set the **Generate Options** in the **Options** block to *Hier Block*, and set a sensible **ID** there, too – don't stick with `top_block`, but use something (without spaces or `-`; it needs to work as a python name) that won't conflict with something else.

Here's an example:

[image: a small hierarchical flow graph in GRC]

You can then [image: generate] Generate button (or press [F5]), and then, after you've done a rescan of your block library with the refresh button [image: Refresh Button] you can find (and use) your new block in the Block Category you specified.

Comment: Great!  This clears things up nicely.  I had read the official GNURadio wiki attempt to explain this, but it was much more convoluted.  To be honest, your explanation here should make its way to the official site.

Comment: Although this method completely works, it still doesn't use the "Create Hier" option under More when right-clicked.  Is there an alternate method which incorporates that option?

Comment: puh, good question. but: what exactly did you read? Did you go through http://tutorials.gnuradio.org ?